# Azure pipeline YAML - install project nuget packages

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a solution containing roughly 100 aps.net projects, one of which is a Selenium test suite. I wish to create an Azure pipeline that installs only the Nuget packages of the Selenium project, and then builds and runs the Selenium tests. When running the VSBUILD step, my pipeline fails, claiming that the project NuGet packages are missing, so seemingly I'm not getting the project packages correctly. I have the following YAML:

```yaml
    trigger:
    - master
    
    schedules:
      - cron: "0 22 * * *"
        displayName: Daily midnight run
        branches:
          include:
          - feature/*
          - release/*
        always: true
    
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    
    variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    
    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
   
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: dotnet restore
      inputs:
        command: restore
        projects: '**/**/Nykredit.Feature.Selenium/Nykredit.Feature.Selenium.Test.csproj'
        includeNuGetOrg: true
    
    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build Selenium Tests'
      inputs:
        solution: '**/**/Nykredit.Feature.Selenium/Nykredit.Feature.Selenium.Test.csproj'
        vsVersion: 16.0
        # platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
        # configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    
    
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: test
        projects: '**/*/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'
    
    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

I get the following error:

```
##[error]src\Feature\Nykredit.Feature.Selenium\Nykredit.Feature.Selenium.Test.csproj(73,5): Error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\..\..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props.
```

Any suggestions as to how to install the packages of **Nykredit.Feature.Selenium.Test.csproj** only?

Comment: Is the `Nykredit.Feature.Selenium.Test.csproj ` depend on any other project from you solution? Can you add the error message you are getting to your question?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej No, it's completely standalone. It's possible, but not preferable, to make it its own solution.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I've added the error message to the issue, and thanks for taking the time to help out!

Comment: One more thing - please add log of your restore step.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Too big to post I'm afraid, but I don't see the packages anywhere in the logs, and I also notice the setting: `ExcludeRestorePackageImports=true`.

Comment: Well, this can be crucial to figure out what is wrong. Maybe Dropbox, One drive?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej The logs are here, and I think you're correct that it's not finding any packages to install: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cr1gib3brbof5i/log.txt?dl=0

Comment: Maybe [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042836/why-cant-visual-studio-find-this-nuget-packages-props-file) and [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/nuget-packages-missing) can give you some help.

Comment: @JakobHandbergLystbæk Please check if you have the same issue and try the solution in [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/911182/devops-tfs-server-ci-build-pipeline.html).

Comment: Hi @WalterQian-MSFT, it appears that my problem was indeed solved by updating or re-adding the packages. Other problems have manifested now, but hopefully, they are solvable as well.

Comment: @JakobHandbergLystbæk Glad to hear that your problem has been solved. Would you add a answer and mark it? This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers. If you have other questions, you can create a new ticket and we will help you on that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While to cause of the error eludes me, the solution ended up being uninstalling and reinstalling the offending package. Presumably, this corrected some differences in versions in the configurations.